# How to debug "Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id" in a PHP program?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a messaging system, where the message id is session_id and it is on a session_regenerate id.

It's working fine but, when I changed my template, it keeps on giving errors like below :

> " Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id -
>   headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\READS Website
>   MAIN\Admin\admin-page\admin\message.php on line 24"

Below is my code:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
include('config.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$id = session_id();
$sender = $_SESSION['id'];

date_default_timezone_set("ASIA/MANILA");
$date = date('m-d-Y h:i a');




$sql = "INSERT INTO `messages`(`session_id`, `sender`, `recipient`,   
`subject`, `content`, `date`, `stat`) 
VALUES ('$id','$sender','$to','$subject','$message','$date','unread')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
session_regenerate_id();
if($sql){

echo "<script>alert('Message Sent')</script>";

}else {
echo "<script>alert('error')</script>";
}

}

?>
<div>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">User</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box-content">


<form action='' method='POST'>

To: <select name='to' class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">

<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['Fname']."      
".$row['Lname']." (".$row['user_type'].")</option>";

}

?>
</select>


<div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5' style='margin-left:150px;    
margin-top:-10px; width:500px;'>

<br>
Subject: <input type='textfield' name='subject' class="form-control"        
id="inputEmail3"><br><br>
Message: <textarea name='message'  class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"             
cols='30' rows='8'></textarea>
<div style = 'margin-left:420px; margin-top: 10px;'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'  value='Send'></div>
</td>




</body>
</html>
<?php include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` query is subject to a SQL injection vulnerability, which means that users could enter into your database value that you would not normally allow in there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting sessions or cookies before any content is sent.
Sessions and cookies are set in the header of a response, and since you can't change a header after the content (body) has been sent, you are faced with this warning.

And after reading your code more thoroughly, I must remind you that this code should not be put into the real world, since you're not escaping any queries. Plus that you should really switch to MySQLi or PDO, since the mysql_* functions are deprecated since a few PHP-versions.

Comment: Thankyou Sir! but what do you think i should do?

Comment: You shoud check if there is any content (including errors/warnings/leading spacebar) before you're calling the session-function. If you think there is no content, look again, because the server is always right ;)

Comment: I've been looking evrywhere for a million times, and I still cant fix it T.T

Comment: Please pastebin `C:\xampp\htdocs\READS Website MAIN\Admin\admin-page\admin\message.php`, because the error says there is something on line 40. Without full source, we can't help you

Comment: the code i gave is message.php. and the error occurs on the line where i put session_regenerate_id();

Comment: That's really weird, because line 40 says `</li>` in my editor. So I think there is a difference in the file when the error occured, and the code that is in your post

Comment: oh im sorry i tried to change the code before i put it here. im sorry i forgot that i didnt paste the new error . the error now says on line 24 where the session_regenerate_id(); is. Im sorry ^^v

Comment: @rown: you can use the [`headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function to check what line and file the headers have been output on.